# variable not found error in mixin

Tags: sass

In a `styles.scss` stylesheet, I import the following elements:

```
@import './variables';
@import './forms/forms';
@import './mixins/breadcrumb';
```

### Content of `_variables.scss`:

```
$errorInputText: #a00f0f;
$errorLabelText: #ad7777;
$lightLabelColor: #ffffff;

$pillsShadowColor: #d8d8d8;
$pillsNoBackgroundColor: #ffffff;
```

### Content of the `_forms.scss` file.

The variables used in this file are contained in `_variables` file. There is no import in `_forms.scss` and the variables works perfectly. `_forms.scss` file seems to be able to retrieve variables from the `_variables` file imported in the parent `styles.scss` file.

```
input {
  &.ui-inputtext.errored {
    color: $errorInputText;

    & ~ label {
      color: $errorLabelText;
    }
  }
}
```

### `_breadcrumb.scss` content:

```
@mixin badgeBreadcrumb($shadowColor: $pillsShadowColor, $backgroundColor: $pillsNoBackgroundColor) {
  background-color: $backgroundColor;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 3px 8px 3px 8px;
  margin-top: 3px;

  &:hover {
    background-color: darken($backgroundColor, 2%);
  }
}
```

Here the sass compiler gives me an error:

```
mixin badgeBreadcrumb($shadowColor: $pillsShadowColor, $backgroundColor: $pillsNoBackgroundColor) {
                                    ^
      Undefined variable: "$pillsShadowColor".
```

If I import explicitly the `_variables` file into `_breadcrumb.scss`, the error goes away.

I don't know why it's different than in my `_forms` file where this works without import.

Comment: Where is $pillsShadowColor defined?  Also of note, in your imports you do not need to use the underscore. SASS knows what it is

Comment: Thanks for the tip of underscore. `$pillsShadowColor` is in `_variables` files. The same which holds `$errorInputText`. I don't get why it doesn't work without import in mixin while no import is required on form to resolve variables.

Comment: You dont need those ' ' either around the imports. Let me ask, you show 3 imports. I hope you are importing them into a scss file then converting that to CSS?

Comment: `styles.scss` is my main scss file. And it's the one importing the 3 files. When I try to convert to CSS, it breaks on the mixin code. But not on the form one. I don't understand why since both are at the same level, included in the same styles.scss file, and use variables from same variables.scss file.

Comment: I would start looking for spelling errors.

Comment: I basically put the whole code in my question. As you can see there is no spelling error.